# SQLite3 Prepared Statements select duplicated results

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm attempting to convert some old sqlite3 database code into sqlite3 prepared statements to improve security on my site. I was considering switching to mysql but as of right now I'd like to get this working first.

I can't see what I've done wrong here, but all of my results are doubled.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = $upc->prepare("SELECT `uid`, `model`, `biosmodel`, `upc`, `systemsku`, `brand`, `hardwareids`, `status`, `pendingHardware` FROM `builds` WHERE `uid`=:id");
$sql->bindValue(':id', $uid, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$result = $sql->execute();
echo "<pre>".print_r($result->fetchArray(),true)."</pre>";
```

My result is an array that has all of my keys, but also duplicated entries that seem to just be regular array keys `0-8` with duplicated information, like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [uid] => 7
    [1] => HP 15-AY041WM
    [model] => HP 15-AY041WM
    [2] => HP Notebook
    [biosmodel] => HP Notebook
    [3] => 889899757697
    [upc] => 889899757697
    [4] => X0H86UA#ABA
    [systemsku] => X0H86UA#ABA
    [5] => HP
    [brand] => HP
    [6] => [42,43,36,44,5,6,45,38,46,41,41,33]
    [hardwareids] => [42,43,36,44,5,6,45,38,46,41,41,33]
    [7] => 0
    [status] => 0
    [8] => 
    [pendingHardware] => 
)
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening, and obviously I don't want all this duplicated information as it is needless. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: it's because you're using both `print_r()` and `fetchArray()`.

Comment: But doesn't `$result->fetchArray()` just hold an array? How do I print the array?

Comment: you can either use a `while` or `foreach` loop. If there are duplicated rows, then you'll need to use DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY.

Comment: But there is only 1 result?

Comment: you still need a loop. .......... I think lol

Comment: Actually @Saty's answer worked, without a loop ^.^

Comment: yeah, *that's the ticket* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm pretty sure I'm going to convert to mysql as I'm more comfortable with it and it's probably faster anyways - but glad I could learn something here ^.^ Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just use `fetchArray()` default it fetches a result row as an associative and  numerically indexed array .

In order to fetch only associative array then pass `SQLITE3_ASSOC`

It would be

```
$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php

Comment: Will approve as answer in 8 mins